# Does Akka clustering (2.4) use any ports by default other than 2551?

Tags: scala, akka

Does Akka use ports (by default) other than port 2551 for clustering?

I have a 3-node Akka cluster--each node running in a Docker using 2.4's bind-hostname/port.  I have a seed running outside a Docker in some test code.  I can successfully send messages to the nodes point-to-point, directly, so basic Akka messaging works fine for the Docker-ized nodes.

My Seed code looks like this:

```
class Seed() extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case "report" => 
            mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.SendToAll("/user/sender", ReportCommand(), false)
        case r:ReportCommand => println("Report, please!")
    }
}

val seed = system.actorOf(Props(new Seed()),"sender")
val mediator = DistributedPubSub(system).mediator
mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.Put(seed)
```

My worker nodes look like this:

```
class SenderActor(senderLike:SenderLike) extends Actor {
    val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator
    mediator ! Put(self)
    def receive = {
        case report:ReportCommand => println("REPORT CMD!")
    }
}
```

When I run this and send a "report" message to the Seed, I see the Seed's "Report, please!" message, so it received its own broadcast, but the 3 workers in the Dockers don't register having received anything (no output on receive).  Not sure what's wrong so I'm wondering if there is another port besides 2551 I need to EXPOSE in my Dockers for clustering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure Akka using port and bind-port, since in docker the "local port" is different from the port "the outside world can reach me at".

In order to do this see this documentation page: [Peer to Peer vs Client Server](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4-M2/general/remoting.html#Peer-to-Peer_vs__Client-Server)

And this FAQ section [Why are replies not received from a remote actor?](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/additional/faq.html#Why_are_replies_not_received_from_a_remote_actor_)